# Plugin for Jenkins to aggregate statuses of downstream projects

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to have following workflow:
run "beforejob" -> run jobs(job1, job2, job3) -> run "afterJob" when job1,job2, job3 are finished.

Job "afterJob" should have PASSED status only in the case if all jobs job1,job2,job3 have PASSED status.
If some of jobs job1,job2, job3 has FAILED status then "afterJob" should also have FAILED status.

It is like [Join Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin), but join plugin runs joinJob only in the case if all jobs have PASSED status.

PS.
I need it to send notification with statuses not from each job, but from one afterJob per group.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

You can add it as a build step and or a post-build action.
It probably won't get you everything you need but it will get you one step closer and sometimes thats all one can ask for.